# Can we reorder the help topics?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

The first thing a user sees in our [help center](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help) is [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) This seems rather unwelcoming. Could the order of the pinned items be changed so that the top link is to [What topics can I ask about here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead? That would be a lot friendlier.

Comment: Site mods don't have the power to change the order of items in the help centre, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Randal'Thor okay ... that seems odd and is certainly unfortunate. But does this mean we're stuck with the current sitch? If *no one* can change it (or if the steps required to do so are too onerous), an answer explaining that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It could probably be done by CMs, but I'm not sure if it's worth bothering them about. (Genuinely not sure, which is why I haven't posted an answer either way here.) I'll ask around other sites' mods to see if anyone's seen this being done before.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better tool available to mods: Use the freeform text box above the list of links instead to provide a short introduction to the site and link wherever makes sense. See the [SO Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for an example of a site that's using this feature.